# Cost of migration to Azure File Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

I wanted to check with you all just to confirm some final numbers.

I would like to migrate around 20 TBs of data (around 40 million files) into Azure File Share or Blob.

I am getting a little confused with the Azure Cost Estimator since it seems to talk about Azure transactions/Operations fees and storage at rest but not the cost to migrate data from On-prem file server to Azure Files.

Am I wrong to Assume all data migrations to Azure Files (Hot, Cool, Transaction Optimized) and Azure Blob (Archive or Cool) are free of charge? Cost will only start after the migration is completed and users start interacting with the data?

Please let me know what the correct answer is here.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about migration.  If you copy files from on-prem to Azure the normal billing meters will charge you for it.  You could use something like [Azure Data Box](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/databox/) to migrate data, but that's a separate service with its own billing.

Comment: so does that mean that if I will be incurring a charge for every file that gets written to the Azure file Share during the migration? There was an article that I cant seem to find anymore that mentions Data Migration to Azure  (Ingress) is free and wont cost anything.

Comment: There's no bandwidth charge for data ingress ever.  But the services you use store the uploaded data are billed as normal. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/

Comment: I think this answers my question. I must've been confusing bandwidth with the data write operations.  Thank you!